# How to style default map marker in Google maps angular plugin

Tags: angularjs, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I am using 2.0.X version of [angular-google-maps](http://angular-ui.github.io/angular-google-maps/).

All the markers are typical Google Maps style (red pointer) by default. While I what to style it a bit - either have the same shape but different colour or choose another shape. Without any custom images/icons involved, just basic but different colour.

Plugin [documentation marker directive](http://angular-ui.github.io/angular-google-maps/?JRwnVeTsM4n98QWm-oHQDw&ved=0CBMQFjAAOAo&usg=AFQjCNGZWf3yx7Vg-YGZEM9xiHCJLP3Oeg#!/api/marker) has a `options` attribute, which is referencing [Google maps API docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MarkerOptions) where is says `google.maps.MarkerOptions` -

**icon**
*Type:  string|Icon|Symbol Icon for the foreground.*
If a string
is provided, it is treated as though it were an Icon with the string
as url.

I've tried applying this like this

```
var pointObject = {
//other props
options: {
  draggable: false,
  icon: FORWARD_OPEN_ARROW //here
},
active: false
};
$scope.points.push(pointObject);
```

but this didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my solution to change marker:

in **HTML**:

```
  <md-whiteframe flex="grow" layout-margin>
    <ui-gmap-google-map center="map.center" zoom="map.zoom" options="map.options">
      <ui-gmap-marker idKey="1" coords="marker.coords" options="marker.options">
    </ui-gmap-marker>
    </ui-gmap-google-map>
  </md-whiteframe>
```

in **Controller.ng.js**:

```
uiGmapGoogleMapApi.then(function(maps) {

$scope.map = {
  center: {
    latitude: 43.6091569, 
    longitude: 57.4442909
  }, 
  zoom: 13,
  options: {
    scrollwheel: false,
    streetViewControl: false,
    draggable: isDraggable,
  }
};

    $scope.marker = {
      coords : {
        latitude: 47.6091569, 
        longitude: 33.4442909
      },
      options: {
        icon: '/marker.png',
      }
    };

    $scope.window = {...};
  });
```

Remember to inject uiGmapGoogleMapApi in controller

Comment: is there an option to avoid using custom images like '/marker.png' ? I just want set the colour (or shape if possible)

Comment: yes it's possible for example you can set icon:  {
      path: google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE,
      scale: 10
    },

Comment: yes, that's it 'google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE' - I just was missing the way it should be passed! Thanks!

Comment: take a look also here https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.21/reference#MarkerShape and here in this example https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/icon-complex

Answer (score 1):

Google provides some constants that you can use for your icons [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#SymbolPath).

[image]

In your controller, use this:

```
uiGmapGoogleMapApi
  .then(function (maps) {
    $scope.map = { center: { latitude: 47, longitude: 33 }, zoom: 14 };
    $scope.personMarker = {
      id : 'personMarkerId', //must be unique
      options: {
        // more options: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#SymbolPath
        icon: { path: maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE, scale: 10 }
      }
    };
  })
```

And your HTML:

```
<ui-gmap-google-map ng-if="map.center" center="map.center" zoom="map.zoom">
    <ui-gmap-marker coords="map.center" options="personMarker.options" idKey="personMarker.id">
    </ui-gmap-marker>
 </ui-gmap-google-map>
```